# PHP: Translate in natural language a weekly calendar availability?

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, nlp

I have in my DB users' weekly availability stored like

```
Monday Morning - yes
Monday Afternoon - yes
Monday Night - NO
Tuesday Morning - yes
Tuesday Afternoon - yes
Tuesday Night - NO
Wednesday Morning - yes
Wednesday Afternoon - yes
Wednesday Night - NO
etc.
```

basically is a matrix 7x3, and i'm trying to find a way to express it in a language like

Mike's available `"MON-WED, Morning thru afternoon"`

or something similar...

my brain is exploding to understand the best way to tackle this.

I'm using PHP, but can be JS or whatever...

Comment: First you need to set down some rules, like what you prefer to group by. If it is weekdays I would create a datastructure (in the simplest case a multi-dimensional array) that groups in that way.

Comment: I'm having nightmares thinking the database is stored like: time -> Wednesday Night. availability -> yes. If that's the case, the first thing you should do is to break the weekday and the part of the day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 possible combinations (from most specific to least):

```
Morning, Afternoon, Night
Morning, Afternoon
Morning, Night
Afternoon, Night
Morning
Afternoon
Night
```

You can identify the combinations similar to the way unix permissions are identified:

```
$111 = "Morning - Night";
$110 = "Morning - Afternoon";
$101 = "Morning - Night";
$011 = "Afternoon - Night";
$100 = "Morning";
$010 = "Afternoon";
$001 = "Night";
```

Your next step is to match days with their respective values in an array, 
consider days of the week as integers ranging from 0-6 (sun-mon). Sunday's availability for ex. should be stord at index 0, Monday at 1 etc.

Set up a loop that does the following. For each day, start off with an empty string. If a given time is available, append "1" to the string. If not, append "0".

This is how your array should look after the loop

```
$day[0] = "110";
$day[1] = "110";
$day[2] = "110";
$day[3] = "011";
$day[4] = "011";
$day[5] = "100";
$day[6] = "110";
```

Now its just a matter of organizing elements of `$day` with the same values into groups. Display the biggest groups first. One way you can do this is with an array like this:

```
$array = []
$array["110"] = "012", "6"
$array["011"] = "34"
$array["100"] = "5"
```

Note that 6 doesn't come after 2, so it is inserted into array["110"] as another element instead of being appended to "012".

Next, order groups by length:

```
012 => 110
34 => 011
5 => 100
6 => 110
```

Now convert to english:

```
Su - Tu: Morning - Night
W - Th: Morning - Night
F: Morning - Night
Sa: Morning - Night
```

Comment: Sure thing! let me know if you run into more trouble!

Comment: $101 = should be i guess "Morning OR night" (not the dash -), because he's not available in the afternoon...

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a matrix, better display it as a matrix, otherwise the text combinations are too many and it would be hard to understand for the users of your application.

```
$s = 'Monday Morning - yes
Monday Afternoon - yes
Monday Night - NO
Tuesday Morning - yes
Tuesday Afternoon - yes
Tuesday Night - NO
Wednesday Morning - yes
Wednesday Afternoon - NO
Wednesday Night - yes';

$a = array();

foreach(explode("\n", $s) as $line) {
    $p = explode(' ', trim($line));
    if(!isset($a[$p[0]])) {
        $a[$p[0]] = array();
    }
    $a[$p[0]][$p[1]] = $p[count($p) - 1] == 'yes' ? true : false;
}

// the availability matrix
echo '<pre>';print_r($a);echo '</pre>';

/* this would print:
Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [Morning] => 1
            [Afternoon] => 1
            [Night] => 
        )
    [Tuesday] => Array
        (
            [Morning] => 1
            [Afternoon] => 1
            [Night] => 
        )
    ...
)
 */

// this matrix can be displayed in a friendly way like this
$rows = array('Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Night');
$cols = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
foreach($cols as $col) {
    echo '<td>'.substr($col, 0, 3).'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row.'</td>';
    foreach($cols as $col) {
        echo '<td style="background-color:'.(isset($a[$col][$row]) && $a[$col][$row] ? 'green' : 'red').';">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

// a nice table with green and red cells will be displayed
```